# WPF - Display 2 dimentional int array as table

Tags: wpf, multidimensional-array

I have `int[40,40]`, contains 1 and 0.

I want to create a 2 dimensional table 40x40, so that a green square represents 1 and red square represents 0.

I also want to add a ToolTip to each cell, and show the index.

Something like this:

[image: Bit map]

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a jagged array first (I don't think there's a good way to bind to a multi-dimensional array, because it is not an IEnumerable).  Then you can do a simple 2-level nested items control, for example:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Bits}">
                <ItemsControl.Resources>
                    <converters:BoolToBrushConverter x:Key="BoolToBrush" TrueBrush="Green" FalseBrush="Red" />
                </ItemsControl.Resources>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" 
                            Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BoolToBrush}}"
                            Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1"
                        />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

"BoolToBrushConverter" is the `IValueConverter` that converts true/false to a green/red brush:

```
public class BoolToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Brush TrueBrush { get; set; }
    public Brush FalseBrush { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((value as bool?).GetValueOrDefault(false) ? TrueBrush : FalseBrush);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I tested this out using a jagged array `bool[][]`, and encountered some strange behavior -- it seems like the runtime was converting each nested `bool[]` to a string.  So I created a wrapper class "BitArray", and made "Items" a type `BitArray[]`, and it worked as expected.

```
public class BitArray
{
    public bool[] Bits { get; set; }

    public BitArray(params bool[] args)
    {
        Bits = args;
    }
}
```

Test data:

```
Items = new BitArray[]
{
    new BitArray(true, false, true, true),
    new BitArray(false, false, true, false),
    new BitArray(false, true, true, false),
    new BitArray(true, false, true, false),
};
```

[image: Bit map]

**Edit #2** Note, since you want to show the index as a tooltip, I suggest making yet another wrapper class to hold the inner bool, along with the current (i, j) index.

Answer (score 1):

Work's great.
I changed it a little bit like you'r said, for the ToolTip.

Here is the final code

Class For 1 Bit

```
public class Bit
{
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

Class for 1 Row (40 Bits)

```
public class BitsArray
{
    public Bit[] Bits { get; set; }
    public BitsArray()
    {
        Bits = new Bit[40];
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            Bits[i] = new Bit();
    }
}
```

And finally 40x40 array.

```
BitsArray[] MyBits= new BitsArray[40];
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    MyBits[i] = new BitsArray();
```

The xaml

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10"
    Fill="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBrush}}"
    ToolTip="{Binding Path=Index}" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1"/>
</DataTemplate>
```